# How to access first made website in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-django-storages

Hi I'm new to Django so just wanted to ask if we create a website and then create another so how can we access the first website created

Comment: do you mean the project folder ??

Comment: Yeah if we created a Django project and then create another project how do we access the first

Comment: if we created a Django project and then create another project how do we access the first 

Like a created first project then did manage.py runserver and did the same for the second project and when i runserver for the first project the content of second project is displayed how to get content to first project

Comment: if i understood your question right the answer is to run them on different ports in first project run `py manage.py runserver 8000 ` and in the second`py manage.py 8080 ` if you open your browser and type `http:172.0.0.1:8000`  you will see content  of first  and go to `http:172.0.0.1:8080` you  will see content  of the second

Comment: Thanks bruh it worked 